# Аббревиатура ЗЫ

Tags: лексика

Очень часто в ответах участников (как на этом сайте, так и на других сайтах, форумах) вижу аббревиатуру ЗЫ. Как она расшифровывается?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это сокращение расшифровывается как "PS" (post sсriptum - лат. после письма). В стандартной раскладке латинское "P" сответствует кириллической "З", а "S" - "Ы".

Answer (score 1):

ЗЫ, как сказал Марк Из, это PS без переключения регистра клавиатуры. 
Часто используется не только по прямому назначению, но и вообще при дополнении к посту или тексту.

Надо сказать, что подобные вещи были популярны лет 15 назад. 
ШЬРЩ, ФЫФЗ и куча и других - это все из той эпохи. 
Сейчас все реже и реже используют...
Я по старой привычке иногда ленюсь переключать раскладку - поэтому остается ЗЫ. А так - выходит из моды.

Comment: Я это на многих форумах видел.

Comment: Все видели. Нормально.